# Update Financial Week based on Multiple Parameters using Pandas/Python

Tags: python, pandas, loops, math, finance

I have a table that is updated manually every week using excel. I would like to automate this process using python/pandas. I want to update  report week number(This number indicates how many times we have reported on that month so far for a given quarter) based on financial week and month. Obviously we are now in September but I will show you the first week to give you an idea of how its updated. The first week for 2021 would start on 01/04/2021 (First Monday of the year) and end on 12/27/2021 (Last Monday of the year).

This script is to be run weekly so next time it is run 01/04/201 --> 01/11/2021, 1 week is added & the "Report Week" should update by 1 too, unless report week is greater than 13. If "Report Week" is greater than 13 than we stop updating that month and add the next month. So in this case we drop December and start reporting March and its report Week becomes 1, as this is the first month we are reporting on it.

| Month | Finance Week | Report Week |
| --- | --- | --- |
| December | 01/04/2021 | 13 |
| January | 01/04/2021 | 8 |
| February | 01/04/2021 | 4 |
| January | 01/11/2021 | 9 |
| February | 01/11/2021 | 5 |
| March | 01/11/2021 | 1 |

When January hits Report week 13 we will stop updating that month and move onto April and give it a value of 1 for tis Report Week and so on for every month.

I am not sure what is the best way to go about this. I read here https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html that one should not update when iterating a df so I'm not sure what to do.

Comment: If you provide your expected before and after tables you'll get better answers

Comment: you could show data before and after. And you could create minimal working code with example data in code so we could run.

Comment: I would use `apply(function)` with own function which checks `value` and returns original `value` or `value+1` . But I think I don't understand your calculations. You should show example data before and after.